# The existence of global continuous frame implies the existence of global smooth frame

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I am trying to show that if there exists a global continuous frame for a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$, then we can find a global smooth frame.

First, I have proven the simple situation when the vector bundle is $M \times \mathbb{R}^k$.

Next, I want to use partition of unity to prove it for the general case. But I am stuck here because when I sum up the local smooth frames, it is not true that the sum is still a frame. So I want to use some tricks to make it still linearly independent for the sum at every points but I have no idea. Can somebody help me?

Comment: A sufficiently small perturbation of a frame is a frame (because the space of invertible matrices is open). So all you have to do is show that there is a smooth frame very close to the continuous one. You proof for the vector bundle should also work for the frame bundle.

Comment: @Deane Thanks! I find that global continuous frame exists iff $E$ is homeomorphic to $M \times R{k}$ (I am not very sure that this statement is true or not). So I think I can make this homeomorphism to become a diffeomorphism, and I am trying to do this.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The existence of a global frame is equivalent to the bundle being trivial. Given that and if you assume $M$ is compact, all you have to do is use the fact that given any continuous function on $M$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a smooth function that is within $\epsilon$ of the continuous function with respect to the sup norm. If $M$ is not compact, then you have to use an exhaution of $M$ by open sets with compact closure.

Comment: @Deane I think your method is the answer. However, I still have some trouble in doing this, I know how to approximate it by a smooth function, but the homeomorphism is just continuous, so when I failed to show the section is smooth after the pullback from $M \times \mathbb{R}^k$, is there anything wrong in my arguments? I would appreciate it if you can write it down as an answer.

Comment: No time now. If in about 2 weeks you still don't know how to do this, post a comment here and I'll provide more details.

Comment: @Deane Thanks for your generous help! I will try to figure it out by myself first.